# Complex condition drupal query

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to add following mysql condition:

```
WHERE       DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'))) YEAR))
AND         DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) +7 >= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'))) YEAR))
```

To my db_select $query->condition:

```
//Build query
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_birthday', 'fb', 'u.uid = fb.entity_id');
$query->condition('THE CONDITION MUST BE ADDED HERE');
$query->fields('u', array('uid', 'name'));
$query->fields('fb', array('field_birthday_value'));
$query->range(0,5);
$users = $query->execute();
```

But i can't figure out how. Simple conditions like =, <> are easy. But i got no clue how to add my more complex condition.

Thx

**EDIT:**
Should pay more attention to the documentation :). Ty!

```
//Build query
$query = db_select('users', 'u');
$query->leftJoin('field_data_field_birthday', 'fb', 'u.uid = fb.entity_id');
$query->where("DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) <= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(fb.field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(fb.field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'))) YEAR))");
$query->where("DAYOFYEAR(curdate()) +7 >= DAYOFYEAR(DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(fb.field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'), INTERVAL (YEAR(NOW()) - YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(fb.field_birthday_value, '%y-%m-%d'))) YEAR))");
$query->fields('u', array('uid', 'name'));
$query->fields('fb', array('field_birthday_value'));
$query->range(0,5);
$users = $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [The Docs for `condition`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3A%3Acondition/7) says:

> Parameters
>
> $field: The name of the field to check. If you would like to add a more complex condition involving operators or functions, use where().

So let's see [`QueryConditionInterface::where`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!query.inc/function/QueryConditionInterface%3A%3Awhere/7):

> ## Parameters
>
> **$snippet**: A portion of a WHERE clause as a prepared statement. It must use named placeholders, not ? placeholders.
>
> **$args**: An associative array of arguments.

Should do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your need use the

```
$query->where(...)
```